# Finding parametric equations of the tangent line to a curve of intersection

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, curves

The question asks to find the parametric equations of the tangent line to the curve of intersection of the surface $z=2\sqrt{9-\frac{x^2}{2}-y^2}$ and the plane $x=2$ at the point $(2,\sqrt{3},4)$

I've seen solutions to questions similar to this one but they use the gradient notation (the triangle) which I am unfamiliar with. How do you do this question? I was thinking of starting with the partial derivatives w.r.t $x$ and $y$ but I'm not sure where to go from there.

Then I thought of ignoring the partial derivative of $x$ since the intersection involves $x=2$ so $x$ is unchanging, so there's that.

Thanks!

Comment: Your curve is $\alpha=(2,y,2\sqrt{7-y^2})$ which is a half circle on the $yz$ plane. Do yo know how to construct the tangent line from here?

Comment: @Dog_69 isn't it a half ellipse?

Comment: @user376343 Probably haha. Well done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equation of the curve is
$$
\vec v=(x,y,z)=(2,t,2\sqrt{7-t^2})
$$
so, deriving with respect to $t$, we find

$$
\frac {d\vec v}{dt}=\left(0,1,\frac{-2t}{\sqrt{7-t^2}}\right)
$$
 and the tangent vector at the point $(2,\sqrt{3},4)$ is $\vec u=(0,1,-\sqrt{3})$.

From this you can find the equation of the line with this direction and passing thorough the given point.

Answer (score 0):

The gradient will give a vector normal to the surface (when you treat it as a level surface.)  But you can get normal vectors in other ways.  A vector normal to the plane $x=2$ is $\mathbf{i}$.   A vector normal to the surface $z=f(x,y)$ is given by $-f_x\mathbf{i}-f_y\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k}$  evaluated at your point.

A vector parallel to the tangent line is the cross product of these vectors.